# Creating eBooks using Affinity Publisher

Tags: pdf, publishing, epub, kindle, affinity

I started using Affinity Publisher and then realized that it doesn't export to .mobi or .epub files. 
So, I exported to PDF and then tried to convert it to an eBook format using Kindle Create. It gives me an output in .kpf format...
My question is whether I should use .kpf format? Will it even be supported in old devices? I'm surprised that Kindle Create is not converting to .mobi anymore. Any advice please? I cannot afford InDesign at the moment and I'm on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

The .mobi format is obsolete, and not supported any more by nearly anything. You will still see it around, but it's generally unsupported. Support for the MOBI format has been discontinued since 2011.
Kindel no longer uses it. They have their own formats as you discovered.

Answer (score 0):

The bigger issue is that exporting as PDF fixes page boundaries, but eReaders strongly prefer *not* to have the document paginated, since the device size varies so much.  So I would say the whole approach is misguided.

I assume you're using Affinity Publisher rather than, say, Adobe InDesign due to Adobe's "rental software" policy.  I've made the same choice and am facing the same "no ebook support" issue.  People are recommending Jutoh, and for US$45, I just may try it.  If anyone else has experience with Jutoh, I'd be interested to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently discovered this too with Affinity Publisher.  If you have a regular wordprocessor (PC or Mac) you can export your document there as word doc (Pages will do this on a Mac) and then take it over to the free Reedsy book editor where you can format it in their dashboard and then export as a professionally designed EPUB or a PDF ready for print.